# The button on header in jquerymobile is out of there

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm not familiar with css.When I insert images above the header in jquerymobile, the button in header at first goes into the images I insert.
Like this[image]

Here is the html

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div style="height:60px; min-width:80px; 
    background-image: url(), url();
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:left,right; 
    background-size:contain">
</div>
<div data-role="header" data-fullscreen="false">
    <h2>aa</h2>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="home"  
    data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
</div>
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel">
```

Comment: Show us some code. Images won't help here.

Comment: I posted it, and all the css is with in.

Comment: are the coke images inside the div with the inline css styles? Without seeing some working code, a hacky way to look at it might be to add something like `style="margin-top:60px;"` to the header div. In all truth though, inline styles should usually be avoided for the sake of maintainable code. Have a read through a css 101 type doc to get the basics down, perhaps something like this: http://wendypeck.com/css101.html